# Singapore Beamer Theme - add bottom bar with author info

Tags: beamer, formatting

I made presentation slides using the Singapore Beamer theme. I think this theme looks very professional, but it doesn't include a bottom toolbar that includes my name and institution. How do I add a toolbar that contains this information? If there are two authors, how would I stack their names, instead of placing them next to each other (which is typically the default)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `footline` template to present the desired information. In the following example code I slightly modified the definition of the `footline` template as used in the `infolines` outer theme; of course, feel free to adapt the design according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in
head/foot}%
  \insertshortauthor\hspace{1em}\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author[\parbox{.2\paperwidth}{\raggedleft Author One \\ Author Two}]{Author One and Author Two}
\institute{The Institute}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output obtained:

[image]

And the footline zoomed:

[image]

Although in my answer I gave a possible solution to the "stacking the authors" issue, I forgot to mention it explicitly: you can use the optional argument of `\author` to format how the author(s) information will be displayed when the `\insertshortauthor` command is invoked (this command is used, in particular, in the `footline`a template above).

Comment: How do I remove the footline from the first slide?

Comment: @AlexRichter: use the `plain` option for the frame: `\begin{frame}[plain]
test
\end{frame}`

Comment: How could I add a hotizonal line just above the footline contents?

Comment: If I use "plain" on the first slide it removes the footline, but also the formatting of the theme. How can I remove only the footline from the first slide?

Comment: @AlexRichter I think those new requirements deserve a new fresh question; the space for comments is not really appropriate to provide code. Please feel free to open a new question with your new problems (you can indicate that it's a follow-up and provide a link to this question).