# Beamer, Singapore Theme Follow up – line above footline and hide footline for single frame

Tags: beamer, formatting

I have two follow up questions to an earlier post: [Singapore Beamer Theme - add bottom bar with author info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49997/3954).

1. How do I add a horizontal line just above the footline contents?
2. If I add a footline to all slides, how do I remove it from the first slide without removing the original theme's properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can use a `beamercolorbox` with colored background.
2. You can redefine locally the `footline` template to be empty for a particular frame.

An example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamercolor{footlinerule}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg,green}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.5ex,dp=0ex,center]{footlinerule}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6ex,dp=0ex,center]{empty}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in
head/foot}%
  \insertshortauthor\hspace{1em}(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}%

\author[\parbox{.2\paperwidth}{\raggedleft Author One \\ Author Two}]{Author One and Author Two}
\institute{The Institute}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]